# How to get from Buenos Aires to Santiago de Chile by land

Tags: overland, chile, argentina, buenos-aires, santiago-de-chile

I want to get from Buenos Aires, Argentina to Santiago de Chile by land. What is the recommended route and what are the alternatives? Aprox. how much it costs and how long does it takes? Where can I book tickets and find schedules? What are the main problems that can be encountered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some **direct buses** from Buenos Aires to Santiago de Chile. For example, [CATA Internacional](http://www.catainternacional.com/) runs a daily bus, on weekdays only (Mon-Fri), which leaves at 17:00 from BA (Retiro) and arrives next day at approximately 12:30 (= duration ~19.5 hours). The price is $AR 900 / USD ~105 (*semicama* without service) or $AR 1050 / USD ~125 (*[cama ejecutivo](http://www.catainternacional.com/servicio-cama.php)*) as of Nov 2014.

Besides the Argentine CATA, two Chilean companies run direct Santiago – BA buses on some days of the week: [Pullman del Sur](http://www.pdelsur.cl/) ([details](http://www.pdelsur.cl/internacional/)) and [Buses Ahumada](http://www.busesahumada.cl/). Prices on Pullman del Sur from CH$ 55,000 (USD ~100).

Alternatively, take the bus to **Mendoza, Argentina**  (12+ buses daily; 13-16 hours, USD 60–110 depending on company and comfort level), located quite close to the Chilean border, and then continue from there to Santiago (about 8 buses daily, 6-7 hours, USD 40-65). The mountain pass and border crossing is called *[Los Libertadores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paso_Internacional_Los_Libertadores)*.

I haven't taken this trip to Santiago myself (only to Mendoza), but I'm fairly sure that the bus is your best (and maybe only) bet, and that you won't encounter any major problems. The coaches in Argentina and Chile are comfortable and reliable. (For a long trip, I recommend investing in *cama suite* or whatever the best option is called, to be able to sleep better.) You can see timetables and buy tickets (with credit card) online at [Plataforma 10](http://www.plataforma10.com/), or you can visit the [Retiro main bus terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiro_bus_station) in Buenos Aires [[map]](http://goo.gl/maps/hVaPG)  for the same.

By the way, Mendoza is a nice place known especially for its wines, and some of the highest peaks of the Andes nearby, and stopping there for a few days wouldn't be a bad idea.

**Edit**: updated for **November 2014**. The prices in local currency keep rising *a lot* (for example, Mendoza–Santiago trip went from 120 to 230 pesos during just five months in 2013). The Argentine peso is weakening at the same time, however, so visitors do not feel it as badly.

Comment: (Oh, locals kept warning me about thieves in/around the Retiro terminal, so I guess I could give the same warning. Keep an eye on your belongings.)

Comment: I just became aware of the site Busbud, which lists [**three** direct connections between BA - Santiago](http://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules/BuenosAires,Argentina/Santiago,Chile) (by Cata Internacional, Buses Ahumada, and Pullman del Sur). Price info seems a little out-of-date though.

Comment: See also [Buenos Aires-Mendoza](http://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules/BuenosAires,Argentina/Mendoza,Argentina) on Busbud. (The site doesn't cover Mendoza-Santiago though, for some reason.)

Answer (score 4):

There are several bus companies that will take you.  The easiest solution, once in Buenos Aires, is to head to Retiro bus station.  Go up to the second floor, and to the section for 'west bound' buses.

There will be several companies.  El Rapido, Andesmar, Cata, Tur Bus, and many more - it's an extremely popular route.

As Jonik mentioned, the [Plataforma 10](http://www.plataforma10.com/) website is easy to use, but note that it doesn't cover all the bus companies.

If you have the time, I highly recommend stopping in Mendoza, for two reasons.  One - it's my favourite town in Argentina, with the best wine around.  Can recommend the All in Monkey Mendoza Hostel, and they run wine tours, or you can use Mr Hugo's bike tours.  The steak is also the best I've ever tasted - El Fuego's restaurant is cheap, and better than any high class restaurant steak I've ever had.

The second reason is that it allows you to get a morning bus out of Mendoza.  You want to be travelling to Santiago during the day - one, because the border crossing at 3am in the snow is VERY COLD (Depending on time of year), and two, the scenery is spectacular.  Seriously, spectacular.  It takes 8 hours (I've done the crossing three times), and is amazing - a great day trip.

Comment: Current phrasing gives the impression that all those companies run direct buses to Santiago. But I suspect you mean going to *Mendoza* and changing buses there?  But yes, I agree about stopping in Mendoza, and will take the mountain route to Chile some day myself...

Comment: With regards to "very cold": do you need to get off the bus at the crossing?

Comment: Yes.  It's a big warehouse/shed thing that allows two buses in at a time.  You go 'indoors' briefly to get some stamps, but then have to stand around in the cold (open) warehouse while they search the bus and randomly inspect luggage.  Then they xray the bags, and you're back onboard.  And the 3rd time I did it, we were queued behind other buses for an hour or so.  But that was during the day so we could get out and take photos - and the view was spectacular :)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry about being brief on my last post  - a tad more info here now.
After going Retiro teminal in B.A. on Friday I was told that there would be no coaches until Monday due to disruption in the high passes around Mendoza.

The good thing is I get a couple more days in the wonderful city of Buenos Aires however I have found this page:

http://www.mendozasun.com/mendoza/37/896-tunel-cristo-redentor-mendoza-argentina-status

It gives a current status of the main pass in English and Spanish.... There is a Tunnel Open-Closed icon just above the twitter icon on the right and current info in the main content.

Hope this is of use....

Andrew

Comment: Hi @Andrew Mottershead We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.