# Bus between Mendoza and Santiago: are there precipitous drop-offs on the edge of the road?

Tags: buses, chile, argentina, santiago-de-chile

I'm planning to travel by bus between Mendoza, Argentina and Santiago, Chile. I don't have a head for heights, hence my question:

Are there any terrible precipitous drop-offs on the edge of the road whilst crossing the Andes by bus?

Comment: From what I've understood, it's safe and [there are beautiful views](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9132/583). But whether it might *look scary*, Mark will surely be able to answer that.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of my favourite bus trips in the world, having done Mendoza->Santiago twice and Santiago->Mendoza once. Please, please, travel it during the day, for two reasons:

1) I've done this once at night.  At the top of the Andes is the border crossing. There's snow a good portion of the year on the hills around you. It's FREEZING in the middle of the night standing in this big warehouse waiting for your turn to get a stamp.

[image: Chilean side of the border crossing]
(from [marksmayo.com](http://www.marksmayo.com/))

2) It's spectacular.  On the way up you can actually see the Inca Bridge from the bus - keep a look out for road signs. Just before the Argentinian border, if you know where to look on the right side of the bus, you have a 20-30 second window where you can see Aconcagua.  The mountains are fantastic, and the roads are actually really good.

Now, in terms of drop offs.  The final time I did this trip was with a friend who does NOT have a good head for heights. Heights freak him out something chronic.  He was fine the entire bus ride.  The roads are good, they have tunnels at key points rather than make a risky road or risk avalanche.

Checking my blog, I didn't provide much description, but...

- [The first two crossings - a night crossing and a day, are mentioned in this post](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/01/10/santiago-the-bicentennial/)
- [The final crossing back to Santiago is in this one](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/01/26/returning-to-santiago-and-reunions/)

Now, there is ONE key point that *might* freak you out a little bit.  I actually mention it in the first post above, as:

> Just before that is a massive series of switch-backs going up nearly
>   vertically, part of which travels UNDER a ski-lift!

This is through the pass called [Paso Internacional Los Libertadores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paso_Internacional_Los_Libertadores) and is a series of 27 switchbacks on the Chilean side.  It becomes almost monotonous going up, but the view going towards Chile (down) is spectacular.  But even my friend with a fear for  heights marvelled at it (and he did the trip twice).

[image: The switchbacks!]
([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Switchbacks_on_the_road_up_to_Tunel_del_Cristo_Redentor.jpg))

But the road has lots of traffic, the buses are very good quality, and the trip takes about 8 hours.  It's a fantastic way to spend a day.

(EDIT) If you really want to see what it looks like, [there's a video of some of the switchbacks showing the drops, but also the inside of the bus and how slowly the bus goes to make sure it's safe](http://vimeo.com/39814438).  You'll be fine :)

Comment: I came across [another video](http://youtu.be/5ScCu2nTWoA?t=5m58s) showing more of the spot with many switchbacks. Slightly more precipitous drop-offs visible in this one ;)

Answer (score 3):

The photos and descriptions on this website might give an idea of how it's like:
[Crossing the Andes: Mendoza to Santiago by Bus](http://hikebiketravel.com/8010/crossing-andes-mendoza-santiago/)